# How can I pass credentials from Angular2 frontend to Spring backend (Basic-Authentification with Spring Security)

Tags: json, spring, angular, spring-security, restful-authentication

I'm developing an application with **spring as backend** and **angular2 as frontend**, The Backend side is secured (with **Spring security**), and I have the default login form when I run it. I want to log in from the client side to the server side but when I try to pass the credentials I have these errors in the browser console

### The configuration class

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity

public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("admin").password("admin").roles("ADMIN", "USER").and().withUser("user")
                .password("user").roles("USER");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http
        .csrf().disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/etudiant/list").hasRole("ADMIN")
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
        .formLogin()
        .and()
        .httpBasic();
    }

}
```

### The security filter in  web.xml:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>
        org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
        </filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
```

### The login form in the angular2 side:

```js
<div class="login jumbotron center-block">
   <h1>Login</h1>
   <form role="form" (submit)="login(username.value, password.value)">
   <div class="form-group">
     <label for="username">Username</label>
     <input type="text" #username class="form-control" id="username" placeholder="Username">
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
     <label for="password">Password</label>
     <input type="password" #password class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Password">
   </div>
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
 </form>
 </div>
```

Comment: You'll have to add http headers to login, you can find how to do that here -  http://stackoverflow.com/questions34464108/angular2-set-headers-for-every-request

Comment: I added the service code in my angular app to my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create an `@Injectable()` AuthService with the following method called by the form.

```
login(usercreds) {
  const headers = new Headers();
  const creds = 'name=' + usercreds.username + '&password=' + usercreds.password;

  headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    this.http.post('http://localhost:3333/authenticate', creds, {headers: headers}).subscribe((data) => {
        if (data.json().success) {
          // window.localStorage.setItem('auth_key', data.json().token);
          this.userId = data.json().userId;
          this.isAuthenticated = true;
        }
        resolve(this.isAuthenticated);
     });
  });
}
```

Do not forget to declare this component as provider in the `app.module.ts` file

Comment: I did like this , I just changed the url in the post method but it shows these errors [ https://i.stack.imgur.com/dsscG.png ] ( I edited my question)

Comment: well it seems your url `http://localhost:8080/studentmanager/login` is not existing, that is why you have an error HTTP 404

Comment: It's the link of the default login page when I run the back-end app , do you think that I have to do a Custom login page ?? If you have any ideas please propose it ! I need suggestions

Comment: I have done my login page on my frontend app which post the credentials to the backend app. In my case with `OAuth2` it works correctly

Comment: I think it's a spring issue

Comment: I changed something in my spring security configuration and now it show's this error > EXCEPTION: Unexpected end of JSON input